# Unable to add iCloud account to Windows 10 accounts

Tags: windows, windows-10, icloud, apple-id, windows-10-calendar-app

I go to Settings, then to Email and Accounts.  I then add my iCloud account, which it says is done successfully.  However, it says `Attention Required` (but not the real error that happened) when I get back to the list of accounts and provides a `Fix` button.

I've done the following:

1. I added two factor authentication on my iCloud account
2. I added an app-specific password and used it to create the account in Windows.

The iCloud account email/username is my yahoo email, e.g. angryhacker@yahoo.com.  However, when I click the `Fix` button, it says *angryhacker@icloud.com*.

So what am I missing?  Why is it not working?

[image]

Comment: Hi, please check if the following link was helpful to you: [How to Fix an iCloud Atten­tion Required Error Mes­sage on Win­dows 10](https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-icloud-attention-required-error-windows-10/)